# how to reduce apache spark memory footprint?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a apache spark full stack+ Apache zeppelin running on a machine with very little resources (512MB) which is crashing.

```
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java -cp /home/ec2-user/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../conf/:/home/ec2-user/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/home/ec2-user/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/home/ec2-user/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/home/ec2-user/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip ip-172-31-24-107 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000daaa0000, 357957632, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 357957632 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/jvm-17290/hs_error.log
```

I know this is a bad idea, but I don't have anywhere else to test it and would like to be able to learn some code in scala + apache spark...

Is there a way I can reduce the memory footprint on spark so I can do my tests?

thanks

Comment: There isn't much you can do with that little memory. If you don't have a cluster available, try using Amazon EC2 with the scripts that come with the Spark distribution, `spark-ec2` folder.

Comment: yep I tried that and it will create a cluster (1 master and 1 worker). I would like to have both on same machine so I can have it running for the whole month...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache zeppelin is a great tool, but I have seen the same thing, takes up a lot of RAM. You could use the command like, in the spark home folder, bin/spark-shell will give you a spark scala shell, but its not pretty and intuitive to use.

You can use Eclipse (scala IDE) or IntelliJ (has a scala plugin)for spark scala development, just need to add the jars with maven or sbt.

You can do your prototyping in the scala shell and copy and paste into the IDE.

Also check out https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook, it takes a smaller RAM foot print. Spark by it self takes less, but zeppelin takes a lot of space, from what I have seen.

Also for scala notebook: https://github.com/alexarchambault/jupyter-scala, then you can add the spark jars to the env, create sparkContext object, and use it.

Comment: Going on the same lines, I was using a 1 GB Free Tier Amazon EC2 instance for Zeppelin. And couldn't figure out the reason for the failure. So, what I did at my end is to scrap the Free Tier instance and created an instance with larger size (RAM). And it worked just fine..